# Adding repeating event registration shortcode in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, civievent, repeating-events

I added my repeating weekly event registration to my wordpress post using [civicrm component="event" id="XX" action="info" mode="live"].
I would like people to register every week for the event.
Is there a way to make the post update automatically to the next week's event (as each event has a new event ID) or do I need to update the event ID each week?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to achieve what’s required with the WordPress CiviEvent Widget extension -

https://civicrm.org/extensions/civievent-widget